# Node app is throwing error in production but not in dev with same package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, deployment, node-modules

I am trying to deploy my first node application to production server in a shared hosting platform but whenever I run the start script I get the following error message:

> returncode: 1 stdout:
>
> thechoicebox-backend@1.0.0 dev /home/ftijpnql/tcb
>
> node server.js --scripts-prepend-node-path stderr: npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is
>
> /home/ftijpnql/nodevenv/tcb/14/bin/node but npm is using
> /opt/alt/alt-nodejs14/root/usr/bin/node itself. Use the
> `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node
> binary npm was executed with. internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
> throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module
> '/home/ftijpnql/nodevenv/tcb/14/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node'
> Require stack:
>
> - /home/ftijpnql/nodevenv/tcb/14/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js
> - /home/ftijpnql/tcb/src/controller/admin-auth.controller.js
> - /home/ftijpnql/tcb/src/app.js
> - /home/ftijpnql/tcb/server.js
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
>   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
>   at Object. (/home/ftijpnql/nodevenv/tcb/14/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
>   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
>   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [
>   '/home/ftijpnql/nodevenv/tcb/14/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js',
>   '/home/ftijpnql/tcb/src/controller/admin-auth.controller.js',
>   '/home/ftijpnql/tcb/src/app.js',
>   '/home/ftijpnql/tcb/server.js'   ] } npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! thechoicebox-backend@1.0.0 dev: `node server.js --scripts-prepend-node-path` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the thechoicebox-backend@1.0.0 dev script. npm ERR! This is
>   probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
>   output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /home/ftijpnql/.npm/_logs/2021-10-05T16_19_33_946Z-debug.log

Although with same dependency and node version the project is running in my system.

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "thechoicebox-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.7.0"
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "http": "0.0.1-security",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "mysql2": "^2.2.5",
    "sequelize": "^6.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

My production node version is 14.x.x not same as in package.json file as that was not present there.

Kindly help me out I am stuck !

Comment: Is it the same machine, or a different machine? I think I've had bcrypt issues on machines without python installed, so maybe check if python is installed on the prod machine.

Comment: Looks like you submitted `node_modules` folder to the server.

Comment: Let me know if this is the case

Comment: no the node_modules folder was generated by the hosting server

Comment: @TJBlackman dev machine is my computer and the error came in hosting server machine and also the issue is in Node not in python

Comment: bcrypt relies on python 2.x - https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#dependencies

Answer (score 1):

I had a "similar" problem with Node when I was debugging and I wanted to change to dev using nodemon.

- Check your `/dist` folder

  - The /dist folder contains the minimized version of the source code.
  - The code present in the /dist folder is actually the code which is used on production web applications. Along with the minified code.
  - The /dist folder also comprises of all the compiled modules that may or may not be used with other systems.
  - The /dist folder also contains all those files which are required to run/build a module for use with other platforms- either directly in the browser, or in a system.
- And very Important:

  - **Ideally, it is considered a good practice to clean the /dist folder before each build.**

This definitely helped me. Hope this helps you too.

Answer (score -2):

Something went wrong in the package installation

you can do for re-install:

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

then

```
npm install
```